# Converting int to char C formula

Tags: c, char, int, modulo

```
int num = 65537;
char p = (char)num; //char = 1;
```

Whats going on here?
Is it `p=num%(127+128)-1`
or `p=num%256` or something else?
I need to know why p is equal to 1.
thanks!

Comment: My question is more: Why your compiler give you no errors? `i` isn't initialized!

Comment: At first glance, `p` has nothing at all to do with `num`, but instead a value `i` that is not shown.  Typo?

Comment: Very likely to be `num % 256` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: In practice on standard processors, it is 1 because 65537 % 256 == 1. The reason is the one ksmonkey123 explained.

Note: If you were writing `127 + 128` because the bounds of a `signed char`, which is equivalent to `char` on typical compilers nowadays, are -128 to +127, please remember that the number of values between -128 and +127 is (127 - (-128) + 1), which *also* yields 256, so it does not matter whether you use the bounds of `signed char` (-128 to 127) or `unsigned char` (0 to 255).

Nitpick: Actually, assigning a value that can not be represented in an signed destination variable, you get undefined behaviour, and according to the C standard, all bets are off.

Assigning a *positive* value that does not fit into an unsigned variable yields "mod range" behaviour, like "%256" for unsigned chars if char has 8 bits. Assigning a *negative* value into an unsigned variable results in one of three possible behaviours defined by the standard. The implementation has to describe which behaviour is used by that implementation. All non-embedded C compilers nowadays behave like adding a multiple of 2^N, where N is the number of bits of the target type, to the value. So "-510" gets to +2 by adding 2*256 to it, and then this +2 is stored in the variable.

Comment: thanks :) so is the %256 method correct?
And why is it undefined? its not that I put char p = 10000;, I put (char) before the big number so it will convert it into char first and then put it into the char variable.

Comment: First: The cast has no effect on the generated code. The compiler knows very well that the destination is a char variable, so it has to convert the value into a char. The cast just makes the *implicit* conversion an *explicit* conversion, without changing behaviour. Many compilers emit warnings on implicit narrowing conversions (as you can lose precision inadvertantly) while they keep silent on explicit conversions (as you explicitly requested to lose precision). Second: For the fact of being undefined, I was actually wrong in respect to C11, final draft.

Comment: Section 6.3.1.3 of the C11 final draft http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf specifies that in this case, behaviour is an implementation defined value (the "algorithm" must be documented and consistent) or result in an implementation defined signal. This is unchanged from C99 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: so its defined or undedined? s

Comment: It is "implementation defined", whether you use the cast or not. So the author of a standard compliants C compiler has to document what happens in that case, and it has to follow that documentation consistently. For gcc for example, take a look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Integers-implementation.html . They explicitly state that the difference of value in the signed variable and the original value to store is a multiple of 2^N, where N is the number of bits in the target variable. That's what they mean by "reduced modulo 2^N".

Comment: so in gcc its undefined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65420/discussion-between-polikdir-and-michael-karcher).

Answer (score 6):

since 65537 is `00000000 00000001 00000000 00000001` in binary, but the char type has only 1 byte, the last byte is considered for the char value, wich is `00000001 = 1`

Comment: This answer is basically correct (just remove the "not sure" and fix the 3 lefttmost byte values).

Comment: note, this is *implementation-defined*, (i.e. the C standard does not mandate this behaviour)